# Jackson JSON Processing key name = ognl name

Tags: java, javascript, json, jackson

I have a class

When converting from JAVA to JSON i want key name to be ognl name
suppose

```
package com.xx.yy;
public Class A{

private String name;

}
```

the out put json should be

```
{
"A.name":"value"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
public Class A {

  @JsonProperty("A.name")
  private String getName() {
    return name;
  }
}
```

[Here](http://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-annotations/javadoc/2.2.0/) is the Javadoc for `@JsonProperty`.

Comment: is there any to do this without @JsonProperty("A.name")? bcus I have classes with more than 1000 fields and there are many subclasses too

Comment: Then you want `PropertyNamingStrategy`. Here is a reference for how to use it. http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2013/04/how-to-use-propertynamingstrategy-in-jackson.html. In your case, you will need to use the `AnnotatedMethod` parameter to use reflection to produce the `Classname.propertyName` you want.